# error is comming for befortrigger my gestcaselist is coming empty what i need to change in my test class

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, before-trigger

```
public class PSAResourceRequestHandler_CLS extends BaseTriggerHandler_CLS{
    
               

    public static List < PSA_Resource_Request__c > psaResourceRequestLst = (List < PSA_Resource_Request__c > ) Trigger.new;

    public static List < String > caseSWOList = new List < String >(getCaseList(psaResourceRequestLst));
    public static List < String > accountList = new List < String >(getAccountList(psaResourceRequestLst));
    public static List < String > productCodeList = new List < String >(getProductList(psaResourceRequestLst));
    
    //Case Query
    public static Map < Id, Case > caseQueryMap = new Map < Id, Case >([Select Id, SAP_SWO__c  from Case where SAP_SWO__c IN: caseSWOList]);
             

    //Account Query
    public static Map < Id, Account > accountQueryMap = new Map < Id, Account >([Select Id,Name, (SELECT Id, Name FROM SVMXC__Sites__r) FROM Account where Name IN:accountList ]);

    //Product Query
    
    public static Map < Id, Product2 > product2QueryMap = new Map < Id, Product2 >([Select Id,ProductCode, (SELECT Id, Name FROM Skills__r) FROM Product2 where ProductCode IN: productCodeList ]);

    //this method fetches the list of SWO numbers which have been inserted from the resource request records
    public static List < String > getCaseList(List < PSA_Resource_Request__c > PSAlist){
        List < String > caseListSWO = new List < String >();
        for (PSA_Resource_Request__c objPSA: PSAlist){
            if (objPSA != null && objPSA.PSA_SAP_SWO_Number__c != null){
                caseListSWO.add(objPSA.PSA_SAP_SWO_Number__c);
                                       system.debug('caseListSWO'+caseListSWO);

            }
        }
        return caseListSWO;
    }
    
    //this method fetches the list of account names being sent from PSA on PSA_Account_External_Id__C which have been inserted from the resource request records
    public static List < String > getAccountList(List < PSA_Resource_Request__c > PSAlist){
        List < String > accountList = new List < String >();
        for (PSA_Resource_Request__c objPSA: PSAlist){
            if (objPSA != null && objPSA.PSA_Account_External_Id__c != null){
                accountList.add(objPSA.PSA_Account_External_Id__c);
                                                       system.debug('accountList'+accountList);

            }
        }
        return accountList;
    }
    
    //this method fetches the list of product names being sent from PSA on PSA_Product_Code__c which have been inserted from the resource request records
    public static List < String > getProductList(List < PSA_Resource_Request__c > PSAlist){
        List < String > productList = new List < String >();
        for (PSA_Resource_Request__c objPSA: PSAlist){
            if (objPSA != null && objPSA.PSA_Product_Code__c != null){
                productList.add(objPSA.PSA_Product_Code__c);
                                                                       system.debug('productList'+productList);

            }
        }
        return productList;
    }
    
    
    public override void beforeInsert(){
        //fetchAndUpdateExternalIds(psaResourceRequestLst);
        populatePSAResourceRequest();
    }
    
    //this method populates initial values on PSA resource request when PSA sends the request first time-US-224579
    public static void populatePSAResourceRequest(){
        try{
                                                                                   system.debug('main method of class');

            for(PSA_Resource_Request__c objPSA : psaResourceRequestLst){
                                                                                                   system.debug('1st for');

                //assignment on case lookup field
                for(Case objCase: caseQueryMap.values()){
                                                                                                                       system.debug('2st for');

                    if(objCase.SAP_SWO__c==objPSA.PSA_SAP_SWO_Number__c){
                        objPSA.PSA_Case__c=objCase.Id;
                    }
                }
                
                //assignment on account lookup field
                for(Account objAcc: accountQueryMap.values()){
                                                                                                                       system.debug('3st for');

                    if(objAcc.Name==objPSA.PSA_Account_External_Id__c){
                        objPSA.Account__c=objAcc.Id;
                        if(objAcc.SVMXC__Sites__r.size()>0){
                            objPSA.Location__c=objAcc.SVMXC__Sites__r[0].Id;
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                //assignment on skill lookup field
                for(Product2 objPro: product2QueryMap.values()){
                                                                                                                       system.debug('4st for');

                    if(objPro.ProductCode==objPSA.PSA_Product_Code__c ){
                        if(objPro.Skills__r.size()>0){
                            objPSA.PSA_Product_Skill__c=objPro.Skills__r[0].Id;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            String errorMsg = String.valueOf(e.getMessage());
            EMS_System_Log__c ex = new EMS_System_Log__c();
            ex.Status__c = 'Exception';
            ex.Comments__c = errorMsg.left(255);
            insert ex;
        }
    }
}
```

*********** test class******************

```
    @isTest
public class ESMX_PSAResourceRequestHandler_CLSTest{
    
    
    @TestSetup
    static void createData(){
        
        Account testAccount=  EMS_TestUtility.createAccount('TestName', '123456789');
        insert testAccount;
        
        system.debug('Account'+testAccount);
        
        
        Contact testContact =  EMS_TestUtility.createContact('TestContact346','345676', testAccount.id);
        insert testContact; 
        system.debug('Contact'+testContact);
        
        
        SVMXC__Site__c  testLocation= EMS_TestUtility.createLocation('Testname' , 'Teststreet', 'Testcountry', 'Testzip');
        testLocation.SVMXC__Account__c=testAccount.id;
        insert testLocation; 
        system.debug('Location'+testLocation);
        
        
        
        Product2  testProduct= EMS_TestUtility.createProduct('testUltrasound System','testU100','X');
        insert testProduct; 
        system.debug('testProduct'+testProduct);
        
        
        SVMXC__Skill__c testSkill= EMS_TestUtility.createskill('testname', 'testU100');
        testSkill.ESMX_Product__c =testProduct.id;
        insert testskill; 
        system.debug('skill'+testskill);
        
        
        id CaseRecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('ServiceMax Case').getRecordTypeId();
        Case testCase= EMS_TestUtility.createCase(CaseRecordTypeId, testContact.id, testAccount.id,testProduct.id,'1.1', system.now()-1 ,'CreateSWO', 'CreateSWO', '1-Critical Need', 'New', true);
        testCase.SAP_SWO__c='12345678910';
        insert testCase;         
        system.debug('Case'+testCase);
        
        
        PSA_Resource_Request__c testPsaResourceReques= EMS_TestUtility.createPsaResourceRequest('12345678910', 'TestName', 'testU100');
        insert testPsaResourceReques;
        system.debug('PSA Resource Request'+testPsaResourceReques);
        
        
    }
    
    static testMethod void populatePSAResourceRequestTest(){
                system.debug('enter populatePSAResourceRequestTest method');

        test.starttest();
                        system.debug('enter start test');

        
        //PSA_Resource_Request__c testPsaResourceReques= EMS_TestUtility.createPsaResourceRequest('12345678910', 'TestName', 'testU100');
        //insert testPsaResourceReques;
        ESMX_PSAResourceRequestHandler_CLS.populatePSAResourceRequest();
                                system.debug(' test end');

        test.stoptest();
        
        List<PSA_Resource_Request__c> listPSAResourceRequest = [SELECT Id, PSA_SAP_SWO_Number__c, PSA_Case__c, Account__c, Location__c, PSA_Account_External_Id__c, PSA_Product_Code__c FROM PSA_Resource_Request__c];
        
        system.debug('PSA_Resource_Request__c'+listPSAResourceRequest);
        System.assert(listPSAResourceRequest.size() > 0);
        System.assertEquals(listPSAResourceRequest[0].PSA_SAP_SWO_Number__c,'jo12345678910hn');
        System.assertEquals(listPSAResourceRequest[0].PSA_Product_Code__c,'testU100');
        System.assertEquals(listPSAResourceRequest[0].PSA_Account_External_Id__c,'TestName');
    }
}
```

*************** error*****************

```
Class.ESMX_PSAResourceRequestHandler_CLS.getCaseList: line 45, column 1
Class.ESMX_PSAResourceRequestHandler_CLS: line 27, column 1
Class.ESMX_PSAResourceRequestHandler_CLSTest.populatePSAResourceRequestTest: line 75, column 1
10:58:13.816 (5819397698)|FATAL_ERROR|System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
```

Comment: Please use the tools in the editor to format your code correctly. Use the `{}` tool or wrap each block in triple backticks (```).

Comment: is it possible to show line number too....?

Answer (score 3):

Your class presumes it's always called from a trigger context. You need to actually insert/update/delete/whatever the records, and not call the method directly. When you do so, Trigger.new will be null and cause null pointer exceptions.